# Meteorjs autoform, collection2, how error should be displayed on client side

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I have following error code in method on server.

```
if(error){
    console.log('Method Errors as invalidKeys: ',error.invalidKeys);
}
```

The result on server console is as follows:

```
Method Errors as invalidKeys:  [ { name: 'name', type: 'notUnique', value: 'PC-02' } ]
```

Can some one guide me how to take this error on client side and display it in autoform code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a local collection at client:

errors.js:

```
// Local (client-only) collection
Errors = new Mongo.Collection(null);

throwError = function(message) {
  Errors.insert({message: message})
}

Template.errors.helpers({
  errors: function() {
    return Errors.find();
  }
});
```

errors.html

```
<template name="errors">
      <div class="errors">
        {{#each errors}}
          {{> error}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </template>

    <template name="error">
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{message}}
      </div>
    </template>
```

Your code:

```
if(error){
    return throwError('Method Errors as invalidKeys: ',error.invalidKeys);
}
```